# How do I get the output of armstrong program in python?

Tags: python

Am facing the error while executing the below code , could someone help on this?

```
def getting_input():
    while True:
        try:
            x=int(input("enter the value"))
            return x
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'error: {e}')
            continue

class armstrong:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Lower = getting_input()
        self.Upper = getting_input()
    def calculation(self):
            res=0
            a=len(str(self.number))
            temp= self.number
            while temp > 0:
                digit = temp % 10
                res += digit ** a
                temp //= 10
            if self.number == res:
                print(self.number)
obj=armstrong()
obj.calculation()
```

Output:

```
enter the value1
enter the value50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\TOM\armstrong using list and dic.py", line 25, in <module>
    obj.calculation()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\TOM\armstrong using list and dic.py", line 16, in calculation
    a=len(str(self.number))
AttributeError: 'armstrong' object has no attribute 'number'
```

Comment: `armstrong` has 2 attributes: `self.Lower` and `self.Upper`. Why did you try to access `self.number`?

Comment: Where did you get that code ? `Lower and Upper` are defined but not used, `number` is not defined but used

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, your 'armstrong' object has no attribute 'number'. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but you are trying to calculate something with `self.number`, but you never made the attribute in your constructor (`__init__`). You should do that first.